# How to use small single image and repeat it all over the window to make it a background image using tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a very small 10 x 10 pixel jpg image that I want to repeat it in the whole background using tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
 
root = Tk()
img = Image.open(resource_path("FILE LOCATION//filename.jpg"))
for i in range(0,1000):
    image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(i)
    label1 = Label(root, image=image1)
    label1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This code this iterating but not sequentially.. I am noob in tkinter GUI development. Please help.

Comment: cant you make the wallpaper in a wallpaper editor and then use it in tkinter

Comment: Yes I can do that as well but I want repetition in sequence programmatically.

Comment: the code doesn't work ?, ```Image.open``` gives an error, maybe you forgot to include the imports?

Comment: No.. my code providing the image on the next line after every iteration but I need it image  repeating sequentially.

Comment: see how to produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the image, or it gets garbage collected.

Create rows of canvases, and put in how many pictures you want in each row.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk

root = Tk()
img = Image.open(resource_path("FILE LOCATION//filename.jpg"))
image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
reference_to_image = Canvas(root)
reference_to_image.image = image1

for count in range(10):
    canvas = Canvas(root)
    canvas.pack(side = TOP)
    for counter in range(10):
        label1 = Label(canvas, image=image1,borderwidth = 0, highlightthickness=0)
        label1.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great!!! It works! But it provides padding gap in between the two images.. Is it possible to join the gap ??

Comment: Can you please check it out my this question also please ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/64958342/10425067

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know much about animate, You should try making an animation in something like adobe after effects and use a video player module in python to play the animation on tkinter