# how to make the width of image longer using animation in tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have this image [image] and I want to make the width of this image longer till the end of the window of tkinter using animation but I haven't got any proper way to achieving this task. any suggestions ?

Comment: Using animation to wider the image ? What it mean ?

Comment: Yes. So it will looks like a polling effect.

Comment: There are `Progressbar`  with `tkinter`

Comment: Yes but is it possible to animate the width of image ? Because I'm looking to increase width using animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with `PIL`:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def work(progress=1):
    if progress > 300: # define the width by yourself
        return
    tmp_images = ImageTk.PhotoImage(progress_images.resize((progress, 10))) # the image size
    lb.image = tmp_images # keep reference
    lb["image"] = tmp_images # change the image
    root.add = root.after(100, work, progress+10) # define the amplitude by yourself


root = tk.Tk()

progress_images = Image.open("path.png")
lb = tk.Label(root, bg="black")
lb.pack(side="left")
work()

root.mainloop()
```

Animation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution!!!! Is it possible to remove the background color and make it transparent by using canvas ?

Comment: @sodmzs "remove the background color" is possible, but I don't know how to make it transparent.